# Python: how to return the actual value of a randomly chosen list item instead of its index

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

I'm trying to create a color matching game that will generate 144 color blocks using random rgb values. I created a list to store my sets of rgb values and I am trying to choose one specific value for the user to match, but every time I try to print the chosen rgb value, it only comes up with one number instead of the three. Here's my code for the RandomColors class:

```
import random

class RandomColors:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = self.get_colors()

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    def value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def get_colors(self):
        r = random.randrange(0,255)
        g = random.randrange(0,255)
        b = random.randrange(0,255)
        print(r,g,b)
```

and here's my code for the main class:

```
from rand_colors import RandomColors
import random

def main():
    randColors = RandomColors()
    colorList = []
    for i in range (1,144):
        randColors.get_colors()
        colorList.append(i)
    num = random.choice(colorList)
    target = colorList[num]
    print("Match: " + str(target))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think my issue is in the `target = colorList[num]` part but I don't know where to go from here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `get_colors()`, and you aren't doing anything with the return value anyway.  All the function does is print.

Comment: Also, you're doing `colorList.append(i)` in the loop, so `colorList == [1, 2, 3, ..., 143]`. Then you're randomly choosing a number from this list (`num = random.choice(colorList)`) and using it to index into this list `colorList[num]`. So basically you're doing `colorList[colorList[random_number]]`. Why?

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to return (r,g,b)

Comment: aah I see what you mean. I'll do something else with that in order to store the rgb values in the array. I'm not that great at this and have only been working on this code for about an hour. Thanks for pointing that out! That will help a lot.

Comment: I changed ```colorList.append(i)``` to ```colorList.append(randColors.get_colors())``` and that worked. Thank you!